# Run method when Accessory is clicked on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a few UITableViewCells, they are all static cells as its a form thats filled in by a user. On one of the cells i have an Accessory icon, i want to run a method (that chows a date picker on the current view) when the button is pressed by there doesn't seem to be any TouchUpInside or similar. I have looked through the documentation, but no joy.

Comment: There's a delegate method for handling someone pressing the accessory button.  No need to capture it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using one of the standard accessory types, the table view sends `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` to its delegate when the accessory is tapped.

If you are setting a `UIButton` as a custom accessory view, you can connect the `UIButton` to an `IBAction` of your view controller.

If you are using some custom `UIView` subclass as your accessory view, you can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it and set the recognizer to send an `IBAction` to your view controller.